# Error connecting ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am working on ActiveMQ JMS Spring application. ***I am using ActiveMQ instance which is present in Cloud server*** and i trying to read message from queue. In a configuration file i have configured broker URL as

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"             class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <!-- brokerURL, You may have different IP or port -->
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://ip address:8161" />
</bean>
```

but when i try to connect it gives me error

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://ip address:8161
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:297)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:286)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1409)
    ... 21 more
```

Can you please suggest me is am i missing something here?

Comment: `ip address` isn't literally `ip address` is it?

Comment: 8161 is port that ActiveMQ uses for itself, please use some other port,
something like `tcp://localhost:61616`

Comment: Some basic read up on how ActiveMQ works is always a good idea before starting. Like what ports are used for admin website and for client connections.

Comment: @Vihar, Thank You, i can connect to ActiveMQ now, i was using 8161 port instead of 61616. But again i am stuck on testing to listener class means i am not getting how i can test my listener class onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) method, can you please give me an idea that how i can test onMessage() of listener class?

Comment: @Vihar Your comment helped me, Should have been posted as the ANSWER